# Adding and editing a drop shadow with original element hidden

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drop-shadow

I would like to create a drop shadow of a person, and keep only the shadow, without the original person. When I double click the layer and tweak the drop shadow setting, is there a way to hide the original layer ? I know that once I created the drop shadow, I can put it on an other layer and hide the orignal layer, but then, I am not able to tweak the drop shadow settings from the "layer style" pop up again...

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drop Shadow Layer Style uncheck option "Layer Knocks Out Drop Shadow" and in Layers palette set Fill to zero.

[image: In Drop Shadow Layer Style uncheck option "Layer Knocks Out Drop Shadow"]

[image: and in Layers palette set Fill to zero]

Comment: great solution thank you so much !